# Building a compatible iOS 6 app

Tags: iphone

I'm not sure how this aspect works as our company is new to iOS development.  We have an app that builds for iOS 5.  We've been running Xcode 4.3.2.  We want our app to be usable on iOS 5 and iOS 6.  Are we ok using 4.3.2 and submitting our iOS 5 app to the app store.  Or do we need to download Xcode 4.5 and build it for iOS 6?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit using Xcode 4.3.2, no problem with that, and submitting with iOS 5. It will run on iOS 6 still.

However, you should seriously consider downloading the latest Xcode and iOS 6 SDK, and making sure your app runs fine on both iOS 5 and iOS 6, as sometimes there are API changes which need to be accounted for and fixed.